# Create a function to upload and import spreadsheet file to google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I have successfully created a button to execute a function that will actually grab the file off on my computer. But will not to completely import the data of that file into a new sheet tab.

My current code is:

**Code.gs**

```
/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog2.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

function upload(obj) {
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(obj.upload);
  return {
    fileId: file.getId(),
    mimeType: file.getMimeType(),
    fileName: file.getName(),
  };
}
```

**dialog2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <form> <!-- Modified -->
    <div id="progress" ></div>
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="file">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data(this.parentNode)" >
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </form>
  <script>
    function form_data(obj){ // Modified
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).upload(obj);
    };
    function closeIt(e){ // Modified
      console.log(e);
      google.script.host.close();
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _But will not to completely import the data of that file into a new sheet tab._ Would you please clarify what you mean by this. Your script doesn't include any reference to a developer key - did you follow the [docs](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) on this?

Comment: No need for the key because it will authorize using the getOAuthToken() I believe.

Comment: You might be right; I've always got a key.